# Django: Can't save a form

Tags: django, forms

I allow users to view and edit a few fields of a database record represented by a ModelForm.
Here is a snippet of the code from the view:

```
def edit(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Record, pk=record_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.RecordForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
```

The problem is that because I don't pass all the fields to the template, form.is_valid() fails with a missing values error. How can I update an existing record with just the subset of record fields  I display to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fields` tuple in the form's `Meta` definition to make sure the form only includes the fields you need - or use `exclude` to remove the ones you don't want.